# WP_User_List -> How to open a new edit-page in WordPress admin backend!

Tags: users, redirect

i'm doing my first plugin and got stuck with linking a row-action to a new editing-site!

What i'm trying to do:

-> Manage User Meta on a special settings site.  Add some fields for documents and other informations about this "customer"

I've started with the boilerplate plugin generator, setting up a high-level menu entry, get all the existing users in a separated list.
Now i want to edit the user-meta from a single user on a special site

-> created a new file html-edit-usermeta-admin-display.php

using the following code in my file class-user-list-table.php

```
    protected function column_user_login( $item ) {     
    $admin_page_url =  admin_url( 'admin.php' );
        // row action to edit usermeta.
        $query_args_edit_usermeta = array(
            'page'      =>  wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['page'] ),
            'action'    => 'edit_usermeta',
            'user_id'   => absint( $item['ID']),
            '_wpnonce'  => wp_create_nonce( 'edit_usermeta_nonce' ),
        );
        $edit_usermeta_link = esc_url( add_query_arg( $query_args_edit_usermeta, $admin_page_url ) );       
        $actions['edit_usermeta'] = '<a href="' . $edit_usermeta_link . '">' . __( 'edit Meta', $this->plugin_text_domain ) . '</a>';

    $row_value = '<strong>' . $item['user_login'] . '</strong>';
    return $row_value . $this->row_actions( $actions );
    }
```

handling the row actions

```
public function handle_table_actions() {

// check for individual row actions
    $the_table_action = $this->current_action();
    if ( 'edit_usermeta' === $the_table_action ) {
        $nonce = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );
        // verify the nonce.
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'edit_usermeta_nonce' ) ) {
            $this->invalid_nonce_redirect();
        }
        else {                    
            $this->page_edit_usermeta( absint( $_REQUEST['user_id']) );
            $this->graceful_exit();
        }
    }
```

how can i redirect to a new page to /views/html-edit-usermeta-admin-display.php, instead fo firing the function as an ajax call?

---

**UPDATE**

---

Some coffee let me come up with this!
If anyone else run in this same situation, some thoughts from a beginner.

**First step: Register a submenu on class-init.php**

```
$this->loader->add_action('admin_menu', $plugin_admin, 'add_plugin_admin_submenu');
```

We need this as "anchor", otherwise we can't link on this page.

**Second Step: Passing a "add_submenu_page" array as callback on class-admin.php**

```
public function add_plugin_admin_submenu() {
    $page_hook = add_submenu_page( 
        null, //parent_slug or set null for hidden submenu
        __( 'Edit User', $this->plugin_text_domain ), //page title
        __( 'Editing User', $this->plugin_text_domain ), //menu title
        'manage_options', //capability
        'edit', //menu_slug,
        array( $this, 'load_user_edit_page' )
    );

}
```

**Final Step: place function "load_user_edit_page" on class-admin.php**

```
    public function load_user_edit_page(){
    $request = _$REQUEST; // request-data eg. action, user_id
    include_once( 'views/html-edit-usermeta-admin-display.php');
    }
```

On this step, we need to include our template from /views.
Now you should have a hidden submenu you can link to.

Set a row-action on **class-user-list-table.php** linked to the registered submenu-page

```
protected function column_user_login( $item ) {     
    $admin_page_url =  admin_url( 'admin.php' );
    $query_args_edit_usermeta = array(
        'page'      =>  'edit_usermeta',
        'action'    => 'edit',
        'user_id'   => absint( $item['ID']),
    );
    $edit_usermeta_link = esc_url( add_query_arg( $query_args_edit_usermeta, $admin_page_url ) );       
    $actions['edit_usermeta'] = '<a href="' . $edit_usermeta_link . '">' . __( 'Edit Meta', $this->plugin_text_domain ) . '</a>';

$row_value = '<strong>' . $item['user_login'] . '</strong>';
return $row_value . $this->row_actions( $actions );
```

thats it!

**My personal thoughts on this** -> Developing in WordPress is great, but i hate the lack of documentation to get things done correctly. The whole thing isn't what i was looking for, to me its more a "hack" instead of an intended solution. Why? Take a look at the top-level menu entry, now you have to deal with a missing active-state. I've tried a lot to get this problem fixed without using jQuery but i failed!

If anyone had some thoughts how do deal with this new problem, please let me know!